# jetty-maven-plugin multiple wars separate ports

Tags: java, maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I use the jetty-maven-plugin for local development testing.  What I want is from a single jetty:run command, start a bunch of jetty containers on separate ports as specified in the pom.xml -- I don't want to specify it within the war.  My current plugin configuration block looks like ::

```
<configuration>
   <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
   <contextHandlers>
      <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
         <war>${basedir}/service-a/target/a.war</war>
         <contextPath>/a</contextPath>
         <allowNullPathInfo>true</allowNullPathInfo>
      </contextHandler>
      <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
         <war>${basedir}/service-b/target/b.war</war>
         <contextPath>/b</contextPath>
         <allowNullPathInfo>true</allowNullPathInfo>
      </contextHandler>
   </contextHandlers>
</configuration>
```

I know I can specify a -Djetty.port but that globally sets the port.  The above example starts both wars in the same jetty container instance running on port 8080.  Does anyone know a switch within contextHandler to set the port or how to do it if I have multiple instances of the entire plugin block?  Every example I've searched for only has the option to set it in the jetty.xml file within the war which I don't want to do.

Comment: What would happen if you created multiple mvn modules under the main one that both received a jetty:run but with different configurations?  (although that usually holds the console doesn't it)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible if you name the connectors and context handlers

```
<configuration>
    <connectors>
        <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
            <port>8080</port>
            <name>instance_8080</name>
        </connector>
        <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
            <port>8081</port>
            <name>instance_8081</name>
        </connector>
    </connectors>
    <contextHandlers>           
        <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
            <war>${basedir}/service-a/target/a.war</war>
            <contextPath>/a</contextPath>
            <connectorNames>
                <item>instance_8080</item>
            </connectorNames>
        </contextHandler>
        <contextHandler implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
            <war>${basedir}/service-b/target/b.war</war>
            <contextPath>/b</contextPath>
            <connectorNames>
                <item>instance_8081</item>
            </connectorNames>
        </contextHandler>
    </contextHandlers> 
</configuration>
```

Note, this configuration is for `org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin`.

Comment: This looks good, but I'm unfortunately no longer in a position to verify if it works.  I'll give it a few days to see if someone verify, but after that I'll assume this is correct and mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

In your jetty maven plugin you can create multiple `connectors` that can run on different ports.  That's a first start.

I'm not sure offhand how or if those `connector` blocks can run different wars.  They can refer to different jetty.xml (although I've had nothing but trouble with jetty.xml)

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html#configuring-jetty-container

Comment: From the linked doc :: "Note that since jetty-9.0 it is no longer possible to configure a https connector directly in the pom.xml: you need to use jetty xml config files to do it."

The only alternative implied in the documentation is to use org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext (used above) and from there it doesn't look like you can configure the port from the pom.xml

Comment: oh, how about that. I've been using 8.